# Python image inside other folder

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a weather program in python, using the [openweathermap.org API](http://openweathermap.org/api). The main file is located in a directory, but the image I want in my `Tkinter` window is located in an `image/` directory. At the moment, I have put the images into the folder of my python script, but there are lots of images inside so it looks untidy. I am calling the image onto the window by:

```
imageURL = str(icon + ".gif")
photo = PhotoImage(file=imageURL)
w = Label(window, image=photo)
w.photo = photo
```

but when I try to use:

```
imageURL = str("images/" + icon + ".gif")
```

it just returns the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 531, in callit
func(*args)
File "H:\Weather statioN\weather.py", line 55, in init
photo = PhotoImage(file=imageURL)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3306, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 3262, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
TclError: couldn't open "09d.gif": no such file or directory
```

Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: The traceback mentions a filename of `"09d.gif"`, not `"images/09d.gif"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback mentions that you still used `icon + '.gif'` -

```
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
TclError: couldn't open "09d.gif": no such file or directory
```

Check if you missed adding the code, or missed copying the image into the images directory from previous testing.

Also, it would be recommended to use `os.path` library to automatically join directories with path using the path separator of the current os , this would make the script platform independent.

```
import os.path
os.path.join('images',icon + '.gif')
```

You can use the above code for your case.

Comment: Sorted it for me. It looks like forgot to add the code telling it to look in the images/ folder. How embarrassing!